# Change page heading of a \chapter*

Tags: header-footer

I got a document that I want to have the following structure:

```
Table of content
Introduction
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/titlepage}
\frontmatter

%Thesis Body
\include{chapters/acknowledgements}
\include{chapters/summary-es}
\include{chapters/summary-en}

%Index
\tableofcontents

%Chapters
\mainmatter
\include{chapters/introduction}
\pagestyle{headings}    
\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}
\include{chapters/conclusions}

\appendix
\include{chapters/appendix}

\backmatter
%Bibliography

\end{document}
```

In the introduction file the code is

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

With this the introduction

- is not numbered as a chapter (as intended)
- included in the table of contents (toc; as intended)
- but the page headings of the introduction take the heading of the preceding toc and not the heading of the introduction chapter (this is not as intended).

How can I change the page heading for the introduction?

Comment: Does `\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}` after `\chapter*{Introduction}` help you?

Comment: yes thank u! post it as an answer to give you +1

Comment: @Stephen ^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A section heading with a star, for example `\chapter*{Introduction}`,

1. does not get an automatic number and the e.g. chapter number is not increased. The last could be done manually by `\addtocounter{chapter}{+1}`, and then the fist by using `\addtocounter{chapter}{+1}\chapter*{\thechapter{}Introduction}` - but this might not make sense...
2. is not included in the Table of Contents, but it can be added manually by e.g. `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`, as you already did
3. does not change the heading of the page, which can be changed manually by `\markboth{left page header}{right page header}` (in the book class) or `\markright{right page header}` (in the standard document classes, article, report, and book) (and `\leftmark` accordingly).